# Emscripten with SDL2 - Error: WebGL: drawArrays: null

Tags: c++, opengl-es, webgl, emscripten

So I'm trying to compile some SDL2 code with emscripten and I'm running into pitfall after pitfall, most I can solve myself but this baffles me.

Currently I'm trying to draw a quad to screen using OpenGL as such:

```
void sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    if(_vboID == 0)
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }

    float vertexData[12];

    vertexData[0] = x + width;
    vertexData[1] = y + height;

    vertexData[2] = x;
    vertexData[3] = y + height;

    vertexData[4] = x;
    vertexData[5] = y;

    //second

    vertexData[6] = x;
    vertexData[7] = y;

    vertexData[8] = x + width;
    vertexData[9] = y;

    vertexData[10] = x + width;
    vertexData[11] = y + height;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), 
                 vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void sprite::draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

This should generate a quad, or so one would think.
Of course, it does not, instead it generates some errors

```
Error: WebGL: drawArrays: null CURRENT_PROGRAM sdl2.js:1:186510
Error: WebGL: No further warnings will be reported for this WebGL context. (already reported 32 warnings)
```

And thus we come to the core of the issue, how would one go about solving this?

Comment: It's complaining that you haven't bound a shader program. If you don't bind a shader OpenGL doesn't know what to do with the vertex data you're sending it.

Comment: Really, I only thought that would be an issue on certain chipsets as it works fine with desktop OpenGL; well I assume that is a major difference between the platforms then.
Thank you very much for your assistance, I will attach a basic diffuse shader in lieu of this information (I was hoping I could wait with that, but I absolutely must know if it works as  inteded in a browser)

Comment: It has nothing to do with chipsets. It's a basic API thing, the same is true for OpenGL Desktop starting with 3.3 (at least in non-backwards compatible modes) and OpenGL ES 2.+.

Comment: Well, it does work fine on some GPU chipsets, it may be incorrect but they still render a white square. (desktop); regardless writing shaders worked as intended, I just had to rework my schedule to integrate the shader compiler earlier than intended but it's all working well now after some trial and error WebGL shader coding (I know GLSL, this version is different though but it's all running now)

Comment: If it works it is by accident, not by design. Per OpenGL standard the behavior is undefined in that case so the driver can do whatever the hell it wants

Answer (score 0):

Like Cubic mentioned the error message says you need a shader.

WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 (not to be confused with OpenGL).

OpenGL ES 2.0 has no fixed function pipeline. It requires shaders 100% all the time whereas OpenGL (on desktop) is 20+ years old and has an old no shaders needed mode. What that means is often things work kind of by accident on Desktop because of all the backward compatibility stuff lingering around where as in WebGL not only is it based on OpenGL ES 2.0 it's extremely strict on enforcement to hopefully try to make WebGL behave the same everywhere so that web pages using it are more likely to function.

If you'd like to test OpenGL ES 2.0 on your desktop and you happen to be using Windows you can use [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject) which emulates OpenGL ES 2.0. Several projects use it so they can target one API that works almost everywhere. Meaning they can target OpenGL ES 2.0 and their code will likely work on Mac, Android, iOS, Linux and Windows (using ANGLE). Because ANGLE emulates OpenGL ES 2.0 it doesn't have the fixed function stuff that is currently letting you do things you can't do and so using it would help you start with C/C++ and be more likely not to use features that are not available in WebGL

Comment: the MESA drivers already provide GLES 2.0 functionality on my desktop, more importantly though is that I don't have GLES 1.0 functionality and to my understanding emscripten uses GLES 1.0 webgl shaders, this is an issue becuase I can't figure out how to pass vertex colors to my fragment shaders (which is fine, I'll just have to color my sprites some other way).

Comment: and after hacking a bit more on that I managed to pull vertex colors as well, it's not working the way I'm used to but it is working so there's that.

Comment: Maybe you should read up on WebGL? It's nearly exactly the same as OpenGL ES 2.0 except instead of `glFuncName` it's usually `gl.funcName` and instead of `GL_SOME_CONST` it's `gl.SOME_CONST`. In other words nearly everything you learn about WebGL can be applied to OpenGL ES 2.0 [Here's a good place to get started](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: I suppose I should, except all I need is the documentation on the GLSL version used by webgl (which I suppose I can find if I read the linked document); the rest is taken care of by emscripten as I'm compiling OpenGL proper to javascript using emscripten.